nvrtc is not limiting register usage
I'm trying to limit the number of registered used to increase the occupancy of my kernel. I'm compiling the kernel at runtime using the options
const std::string temp = arch.str();
std::array<const char *, 10> options({
    temp.c_str(),
    "--std=c++17",
    "--relocatable-device-code=false",
    "--include-path=" CUDA_INCLUDE,
    "--include-path=" HEADER_DIR,
    "--extra-device-vectorization",
    "--device-as-default-execution-space",
    "--maxrregcount=32",
    "--ptxas-options",
    "-dlcm=cg"
});

nvrtcCompileProgram(kernel_program, options.size(), options.data())

When the profile the kernel, it shows it's using more than my limit of 32. Is there something overriding this?

Maybe there is an issue that I don't see at the moment, however, in general CUDA will ignore this setting if the compiler cannot fulfill the required limit. See for example here a case where 40 registers were too little: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3795

Can you please provide a minimal reproduction example? Thanks!

@Homer512 When I restrict the kernels using __launch_bounds(1024), the compiler has no problems creating a kernel that uses only 32 registers.

nvrtc was only generating a ptx intermediate representation. Registers are not scheduled until I load the module data. The correct way to limit registers is to pass the CU_JIT_MAX_REGISTERS option to cuModuleLoadDataEx.
std::array<CUjit_option, 1> module_options = {
    CU_JIT_MAX_REGISTERS
};
std::array<void *, 1> module_values = {
    reinterpret_cast<void *> (32)
};

cuModuleLoadDataEx(&module, ptx, 1,
                   module_options.data(),
                   module_values.data());

